# How do I rank search results by best match in mysql/php?

Tags: php, mysql

This is for MySQL/PHP scenario:

Let's say I need to find professionals based on their qualification. Now assume the search input is "CA,BA".

1. I want it to match, 'CA','MCA','BCA','MBA',... which can be easily done by using `LIKE` or even `REGEXP` in MySQL if I disregard performance, now 'CA' is the exact match so I want a user with `CA` in his profile to be ranked higher than others.
2. Since I am searching for two entries, I want the resulting list to be further sorted based on whether the person matches(or partially matches) both qualifications instead of a single one.

For the first one I guess I can use levenshtein distance but I am worried about performance. But for the second one I have no idea at all. So my question is how to do this in the most performance efficient way?

All ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levenshtein would likely be slow, but possible

Do one query for each value to check, getting the MIN lenvenshtein distance. Do a UNION ALL of the 2 queries, and use that as a sub query to select the person and the SUM of the min distances, and order by that value descending.

EDIT

Assuming you can redesign the tables

Have 3 tables:-

**Table of professionals**
Id
Name
...

**Table of qualifications**
Id
QualificationName

**LinkTable**
ProfessionalId
QualificationId

Then do a a query that does a subselect for the levenshtein distance for the qualifications (which should mean only doing it per qualification, not per persons qualification):-

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Relevancy) AS SumRelevancy
FROM
(
    SELECT a.Name, MIN(c.Relevancy) AS Relevancy 
    FROM Professionals a
    INNER JOIN LinkTable b ON a.Id = b.ProfessionalId
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT QualificationId, LEVENSHTEIN('CA', QualificationName) AS Relevancy FROM Qualifications
    ) c ON b.QualificationId = c.QualificationId
    GROUP BY a.Name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.Name, MIN(c.Relevancy) AS Relevancy 
    FROM Professionals a
    INNER JOIN LinkTable b ON a.Id = b.ProfessionalId
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT QualificationId, LEVENSHTEIN('BA', QualificationName) AS Relevancy FROM Qualifications
    ) c ON b.QualificationId = c.QualificationId
    GROUP BY a.Name
) Sub1
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY SumRelevancy
```

Comment: Will work, but even if I turn this logic in a Stored Procedure, I believe it's gonna be extremely slow considering a database of a few thousand users to look through. Maybe I can store the soundex of the values beforehand in a reference table...but I still think if I let mysql do this entire thing by itself it's gonna be real slow? Isn't there any way to combine php and mysql together to make things more optimized?

Comment: Anything like this is going to be slow. Levenshtein is not that quick, and as it needs to compare the values you can't really calculate it in advance. Soundex would be useless as the first character must match, and also it is designed for European names and doesn't work so well for general words and non European names. Can you change the database design?

Comment: Edited to suggest a solution if you can redesign the tables

Answer (score 0):

I would search for the Exact matches, throw them in an array, then search for the Like matches and throw them in an array.

Finally I would do an array_diff and result is there.